# How can I configure the color of file paths and links in VS Code's integrated terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

At present, the color of the output content from the VS Code terminal is the same. I want to match the output content from the PyCharm terminal: the color of the output file path will be specially marked, how should I set it?

such as : The "/xxx/file/path" color is red
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qbTV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, at the time of this writing, there is no colour customization point for links in the terminal. (VS Code does have automatic file path detection in its integrated terminal to create document links). Neither of the `textLink.foreground` or the `textLink.activeForeground` customization points apply to links in the integrated terminal. If you want file paths to be coloured differently in the terminal, then the colours will have to be specified by the program writing to the terminal by using something like ANSI escape codes in its output.

If you want VS Code to have such a colour customization point feature, then you should [raise a feature-request issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md).

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to the issue ticket, or notify me in the issue ticket with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.